# Can we parameterize HTTP Body

Tags: katalon-studio, web-api-testing, data-driven-tests

I am sending an API POST request from Katalon Studio. Can I parameterize the HTTP Body? If yes how can I do that? Can I use Internal Test Data or data source like Excel to get the data in HTTP Body?

```
"Dummy":'${dType}',
"DD":{  
            "DR":"2019-04-11"         
   },
```

Comment: Please add an MCVE.

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can [parametrize a Web Service Object](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/parameterize-a-web-service-object.html#query-parameters), you will probably need to use something like this:

```
response = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('requestObject',[('variable'): value]))
```

Or use [setHTTPBody() method](https://api-docs.katalon.com/studio/v4.6.0.2/api/com/kms/katalon/core/testobject/RequestObject.html#setHttpBody(java.lang.String)) for setting the HTTP.

There are also some examples on the Katalon forum page so I recommend you look [here](https://forum.katalon.com/t/parameterizing-http-body-for-api-testing/11752), [here](https://mitch.codes/rest-api-testing-with-katalon/) or [here](https://forum.katalon.com/t/parameterize-a-web-service-object/10924).

Answer (score 1):

You can add HTTP Body via Object Repository using Web service request or you can set HTTP Body manually by using script.

If you want to set HTTP Body manually using script, you can use following script:

```
// defining body parameter
def params = '{ "id": 1, "name":"John", "lastName":"Smith" }
RequestObject get_object = findTestObject(here goes web service request configured with url)
//setting HTTP Body Content
get_object.setBodyContent(new HttpTextBodyContent(params))
```

You should have import these:

```
import import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.RequestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ResponseObject
```

You can also learn much more, according to previous answer by Mate Mrse