# Katalon API Testing: How to pass two or more json data

Tags: api, rest, katalon-studio, katalon

Hope all are safe and good.
I'm about to test API in Katalon tool, I'm having an Login API (https://abc.api.xyz.com/user/authenticate), I want to test the given API by passing Login JSON data (contains username and password)(as given in below attached image1).

**Image1**:
[image]

When testing above scenario gets result pass.

If I want to test the same API with invalid data, do we need to create separate **Object Repository**(alike given in Image2) for each scenario or do we have any alternate way to pass two or more JSON data to one **Object Repository**

**Image2**:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some introductory topics in Katalon docs:

- [REST Request](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/restful.html)
- [Parametrize a Web Service Object](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/parameterize-a-web-service-object.html)

More specifically to your case, you can read these two posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640930/can-we-parameterize-http-body/55647487#55647487), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430247/how-to-passing-json-parameters-for-test-api-restful-in-katalon-studio)).

You could probably use something like:

```
response = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('requestObject',[('variable'): value]))
```